# Change HTML input field to label by defining custom angular directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have lots of input, textarea and select on some pages (angular templates).
I want to redefine "input" directive such that It will take a value like `ViewMode = true` from either **localStorage** and convert all inputs as label. If I change the `ViewMode` then on page refresh input should behave properly.

But I do not want to edit any input tag on any angular template.

Means I want to override input, textarea and select as my own angular directive.

I am not able to start. Where from should I start? (I have experience of custom directive with new name, but not with any exciting HTML tag name)

**Note**: I do not want to use readonly (with proper style) since it requires editing all input tag. Not only that I have custom directives with isolated scope, so I need to pass the ViewMode value to all custom directives. More over if user press CTRL+A content readonly field is not being selected.

I am looking for a solution kind of as follows

```
ViewButtonClickEvent () {
   set localStorage.viewMode = true;
   callExistingEditMethod();
}

EditButtonClickEvent () {
  set localStorage.viewMode = false;
  callExistingEditMethod();
}

editPagesModule.directive('input', {
    if(localStorage.viewMode != true)
     //Keep all existing functionality with ng-model
    }
    else {
      //replace input with span or label.
    }
})
```

Comment: perhaps it is decorator you're looking for.

Comment: Angular directive can not only be an element but also an attribute or class, right? Just make a directive as an attribute or class that can be added to <input>, <textarea> or <select> will that serve your purpose?

Comment: ng-readonly is there but I dont like to use it because I have to update all input tag. I want some centralize approch. So that I don't need to tuch any thing.

Comment: Looks like you need 'in place edit' functionality. There are many examples over the Internet [example](http://jsfiddle.net/joshdmiller/NDFHg/) (not mine).

Comment: Nice one. But it should not be with isolated scope. It should work with existing ng-model and others ng directive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create directives called `input`, `select` and `textarea`, which would automatically be compiled without having to change your existing markup.

Working examples: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sscovil/kpfpwg2k/) & [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/6a5X9aRA6IXRsd9ZUteP?p=preview)

It would look something like this:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .directive('input', inputDirective)
  .directive('select', inputDirective)
  .directive('textarea', inputDirective)
  .factory('$editMode', editModeFactory)
;

inputDirective.$inject = ['$editMode'];
function inputDirective($editMode) {
  return {
    link: postLink
  };

  function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttr) {
    scope.$watch($editMode.get, function(edit) {
      if (iElement[0].nodeName === 'SELECT') {
        if (edit === 'true') iElement.removeAttr('disabled');
        else iElement.attr('disabled', true);
      }
      else {
        if (edit === 'true') iElement.removeAttr('readonly');
        else iElement.attr('readonly', true);
      }
    });
  }
}

editModeFactory.$inject = ['$window'];
function editModeFactory($window) {
  return {
    get: function() {
      return $window.localStorage.getItem('editMode');
    },
    set: function(value) {
      $window.localStorage.setItem('editMode', value);
    }
  };
}
```

I did use the `readonly` attribute (`disabled` for select), because the only other option I can think of would be to replace the entire input element with something like a div. You would also have to cache the original element, so you can restore it later...and doing that sort of thing would break your bindings so you'd have to recompile every input, every time. That just seems like a horrible idea.

Comment: Very nice approach. But I am not able to open jsfiddle from my workplace. So can you please clone it on plunker? One more thing some of my user will not have edit permission so I do not need to recompile to edit view. More over view mode and edit mode are completely different flow so we do not need to come back vice versa any time.

Comment: I added a plunker to my answer. If you would prefer to change the inputs to divs, you might be able to do something like `iElement.replaceWith('<div>' + iElement.val() + '</div>');`, but you will lose any bindings, classes and other attribute values on the input (unless you explicitly add them to your html string).

Comment: Wow! that is great. I will try this and let you know what happens. Your plunker is blank URL here.

Comment: Sorry, I fixed the link for plnkr.co: http://plnkr.co/edit/6a5X9aRA6IXRsd9ZUteP?p=preview